# How to filter out nested List in Java 8

Tags: java

```
package com.example.java;

public class C {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.java;

import java.util.List;

public class B {

    List<C> listC;

    public List<C> getListC() {
        return listC;
    }

    public void setListB(List<C> listC) {
        this.listC = listC;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [listC=" + listC + "]";
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.java;

import java.util.List;

public class A {

    List<B> listB;

    public List<B> getListB() {
        return listB;
    }

    public void setListB(List<B> listB) {
        this.listB = listB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [listB=" + listB + "]";
    }
}
```

I have a list of A class object, want to filter out C where name is "C1"

List of A --> List of B --> List of C (filter out if c.getName().equals("C1"))

Comment: There is no `List of A` in your code. But lets even assume there is one, your question is still unclear because we don't know from which list you want to "*filter out C where name is "C1"*".

Comment: So do you only want to ignore only `C` from all `List<C>`, or you want to ignore each `B` which List<C> *contains* any/all C elements with specified name? Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to modify the existing lists, not create new list instances:

```
A a = ...
for (B b : a.getListB()){
    Iterator<C> iterator = b.getListC().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next().getName().equals("C1")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use streams and create new, filtered lists:

```
A a = ...
a.getListB().forEach(b -> {
    b.setListB(b.getListC().stream()
     .filter(c -> !c.getName().equals("C1"))
     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
});
```

Comment: Not a java 8 based answer. Also you're removing the elements, modifying the contents of the list. I think this is not what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex yeah, I was just writing the stream version.

Comment: Avoid using inverted checks in predicates. It's always better to negate the predicate to improve readability.

Comment: And how would you suggest removing items that match some condition using streams?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using streams, the only thing you'll need to do is to `flatMap` and stream the inner lists, finally acquiring a `Stream<C>`. You can then go ahead and filter that stream out using the name attribute.

```
var someList = List.of(new A(), new A());
var filtered = someList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
        .flatMap(b -> b.getListC().stream())
        .filter(((Predicate<? super C>) c -> c.getName().equals("something")).negate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep the lists in place, not get all C elements that match that condition. Although that's a plausible interpretation of the question too.

Comment: Also, OP wants to filter *out* `C` whose name is equal to something. You're keeping the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in case you are concerned with only objects of C:

```
 list.stream().forEach( a -> {
            a.getListB().stream().forEach( b -> {
                b.getListC().stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals("C1")).forEach( c-> {
                    // Write your code.
                });
            } );
        });
```

You can also use [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

```
        A a0=new A();
        A a1=new A();

        List<A> sourceList = Arrays.asList(a0, a1);

        B b0= new B();
        B b1= new B();
        B b2= new B();
        B b3= new B();

        C c0=new C();
        C c1=new C();
        C c2=new C();
        C c3=new C();

        c0.name="ciao";
        c1.name="C1";
        c2.name="hello";
        c3.name="C1";


        b0.listC=new ArrayList(){{add(c0); add(c1);}};
        b1.listC=new ArrayList(){{add(c2); add(c3);}};

        a0.listB=new ArrayList(){{add(b0); add(b1);}};
        a1.listB=new ArrayList(){{add(b2); add(b3);}};


          //ALL A THAT CONTAINS C1    
    List<A> allAContainsC1Objects =  sourceList
            .stream().filter( a-> Optional.ofNullable(a.getListB()).orElseGet(()-> new ArrayList<>()).stream()
                    .filter(b->Optional.ofNullable(b.getListC()).orElseGet(()-> new ArrayList()).stream()
                            .filter(c-> ((C)c).getName().equals("C1")).count()>0)
                    .count()>0).collect(Collectors.toList());


    //ALL C OBJECT C1
    List<C> allCObjectMatchedC1 = sourceList.stream().filter(a -> Optional.ofNullable(a.getListB()).isPresent())
            .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
            .filter(b -> Optional.ofNullable(b.getListC()).isPresent())
            .flatMap(b -> b.listC.stream())
            .filter(c-> Optional.ofNullable(c.getName()).isPresent()&&c.name.equals("C1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

  //ALL A OBJECT WITH C1 only  
  final  List<A>  AllAObjectWithC1Only=  sourceList
          .stream()
          .filter( a-> Optional.ofNullable(a.getListB()).orElseGet(()-> 
          new ArrayList<>()).stream()
                  .filter(b->Optional
                  .ofNullable(b.getListC()).isPresent())
                  .peek(b-> {
                      Iterator<C> i = b.getListC().iterator();
                      while (i.hasNext()) 
                   {if(i.next().getName().equals("C1")==false) 
                  {i.remove();}}
                  } ).count()>0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need List of A so I cant use flatMap.

Comment: Ok sorry, i changed the code, i was read "want to filter out C where name is "C1". Hope can help.

Comment: C c1 = new C();
  C c2 = new C();
  C c3 = new C();
  c1.setName("C1");
  c2.setName("C2");
  c3.setName("C3");
  B b1 = new B();
  B b2 = new B();
  A a1 = new A();
  A a2 = new A();
  List<C> lc =  new ArrayList<>();
  lc.add(c1);
  lc.add(c2);
  List<C> lc2 =  new ArrayList<>();
  lc2.add(c3);
  List<B> lb =  new ArrayList<>();
  b1.setListB(lc);
  lb.add(b1);
  List<B> lb2 =  new ArrayList<>();
  b2.setListB(lc2);
  lb2.add(b2);
  List<A> la = new ArrayList<>();
  a1.setListB(lb);
  a2.setListB(lb2);
  la.add(a1);
  la.add(a2);

Comment: [A [listB=[B [listC=[C [name=C1], C [name=C2]]]]]]

Comment: but output I am expecting [A [listB=[B [listC=[C [name=C1]]]]]]

Comment: Your example is giving output [A [listB=[B [listC=[C [name=ciao], C [name=C1]]], B [listC=[C [name=hello], C [name=C1]]]]]] but expected output is [A [listB=[B [listC=[C [name=C1]]], B [listC=[C [name=C1]]]]]]

Comment: ok, i understand, do you need also to preserve the original source object or not?